# Getting new position for a component placed in an image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an image. I placed that image on a PictureBox. Within the image, I have to place some tool box components. At design time, I drag components and place them at their respective positions on the image. When the form was maximized, the image was fitting to the form. But how can I get the new co-ordinates, height and width for the components placed on the image?

For calculating width and height, I used the calculations shown below:

```
New Width = (originalWidth * current form width)/original form width;                          
New Height = (original height * current form height)/original form height;
```

The height and width was changing according to the form width and height, but how can I get the top and left positions?

Comment: Could you please clarify in better detail and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same method, assuming the original left and top positions are known.

ie:

New Left = (originalLeft * current form width)/original form width;
New Top = (original Top * current form height)/original form height;

Comment: current form width / original form width is the x scaling factor etc